# notepad++ regex to clean .txt of lines with less than X characters or only spaces

Tags: regex

I'm using this `^.{0,10}(\r\n?|\n|$)` to clean my .txt files from lines with less than 10 characters and it works great so far.

The problem I have is that the `SPACE` is counted as a character and I have lines containing only spaces or lots of spaces and few other characters
and I want to remove those lines too. 
Please help me with the correct regex to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

How about "trimming" the line? That is, accepting (or ignoring, whatever you call it) spaces (`\s*`) before or after the string.

```
^\s*.{0,10}\s*(\r\n?|\n|$)
 ^^^       ^^^
  '---------'---- added these \s*
```

See [regex 101 demo here](https://regex101.com/r/cX7hQ5/1).

Comment: Thank you for helping, your code almost works except that I'm still left with lines like: `SPACESPACESPACESPACE16SPACESPACE16SPACE30`

Comment: Well, it seems to work: https://regex101.com/r/qS3rV6/1 see as it (the line before the last) gets matched (and thus removed)...

Comment: I've posted a sample text [here](http://pasted.co/5e7d86f4) . Can you please copy/paste "as is" into a .txt file and run your code against it.

Comment: Hm. I tried it out. Can you test this expression: `^\s*(\S\s*){0,10}\s*(\r\n?|\n|$)` Does it work? The blue parts are what it will remove (match): https://regex101.com/r/cX7hQ5/2

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this properly, you want to count all whitespace as zero characters? This should work

```
^([\S]?[\s]*){0,10}(\r\n?|\n|$)
```

This will match any lines with 10 or fewer characters that are NOT whitespace